# Radio button css works with checked, but doesn't work with unchecked

Tags: css

I have the following code (css+html):

```css
.c-form__radio__input {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; }
  .c-form__radio__label {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 calc(2px + 1rem);
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1; }
    .c-form__radio__label::before, .c-form__radio__label::after {
      content: '';
      width: calc(0.8rem + 2px);
      height: calc(0.8rem + 2px);
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(0.5rem - 1px);
      left: 0;
      background-color: transparent; }
    .c-form__radio__label::before {
      border-color: #bdc3c7; }
    .c-form__radio__label::after {
      transform: scale(0.6); }
    .c-form__radio__input:checked + .c-form__radio__label::after {
      background-color: blue; }
    .c-form__radio__input:not(:checked) + .c-form__radio__label::after {
      background-color: transparent; }
```

```html
<div class="c-form__radio">
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" class="c-form__radio__input" name="radio1"/>
            <label for="radio1" class="c-form__radio__label">First radio</label>
        </div>
```

The code is working for check, but clicking again for uncheck is not working.

If I start unchecked and click checked is working, clicking again doesn't work; Starting checked, and clicking doesn't work;

Comment: You can't uncheck radio button

Comment: You need at least 2 radio buttons to uncheck one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `radio` buttons can't be unchecked unless clicked on another one sharing the same `name` attribute, you may use a `checkbox` instead.

`<input id="radio1" type="checkbox" class="c-form__radio__input" name="radio1"/`>

Hope this helps.